Cloud exported animation produces strange circle shape when changing one of the levers on animation
This is exported animation to Mathematica cloud: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8af73931-749a-4e15-bd24-874ef26ee8b6
Has anyone encountered the following issue?

It does not show straight away. When loaded up the first time, it looks okay, but when I change one of the parameters, it displays those strange shapes.
The code is rather lengthy, I got that from chatGPT :)
Manipulate[
 Module[{binomialDistribution, observations, likelihoodProbs, 
   posteriorProbs, pdfPlot, likelihoodPlot, samplePlot, betaPlot, 
   posteriorPlot},(*Define the Binomial distribution*)
  binomialDistribution = BinomialDistribution[n, theta];
  (*Generate a sequence of random observations*)SeedRandom[0];
  observations = RandomVariate[binomialDistribution, 10];
  (*Calculate the likelihood function*)
  likelihood[theta_, observations_] := 
   Product[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, theta], x], {x, 
     observations}];
  (*Calculate the likelihood probabilities*)
  likelihoodProbs = likelihood[#, observations] & /@ thetaValues;
  (*Calculate the posterior probabilities*)
  posteriorProbs = 
   posterior[#, observations, alpha, beta] & /@ thetaValues;
  posteriorProbs = 
   posteriorProbs/
    Total[posteriorProbs];(*Normalize*)(*Plot the PDF of the Binomial \
distribution*)
  pdfPlot = 
   DiscretePlot[PDF[binomialDistribution, k], {k, 0, n}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> {"Binomial PDF"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"k", "Probability"}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Row[{"PDF of Binomial Distribution (", 
       Style["θ = " <> ToString[NumberForm[theta, {3, 2}]], 
        Red], ")"}]];
  (*Plot the likelihood function and display the generated sample*)
  likelihoodPlot = 
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{thetaValues, likelihoodProbs}], 
    PlotStyle -> Green, PlotLegends -> {"Likelihood"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Likelihood"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Likelihood Function"];
  samplePlot = 
   ListPlot[observations, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Generated Sample"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Index", "Value"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Generated Sample from Binomial Distribution"];
  (*Define the Beta distribution*)
  betaDistribution = BetaDistribution[alpha, beta];
  (*Plot the PDF of the Beta distribution*)
  betaPlot = 
   Plot[PDF[betaDistribution, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Prior Beta PDF"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Probability Density"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "PDF of Prior Beta Distribution"];
  (*Plot the posterior distribution*)
  posteriorPlot = 
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{thetaValues, posteriorProbs}], 
    PlotStyle -> Purple, PlotLegends -> {"Posterior"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Probability Density"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Posterior Distribution"];
  (*Display the plots in a 2x2 grid*)
  GraphicsGrid[{{pdfPlot, likelihoodPlot}, {samplePlot, 
     betaPlot}, {posteriorPlot, SpanFromLeft}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]], {{alpha, 2, "Alpha"}, 0.1, 10, 
  0.1}, {{beta, 2, "Beta"}, 0.1, 10, 0.1}, 
 Initialization :> (SeedRandom[0];
   n = RandomInteger[{10, 20}];
   theta = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
   thetaValues = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
   likelihood[theta_, observations_] := 
    Product[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, theta], x], {x, observations}];
   posterior[theta_, observations_, alpha_, beta_] := 
    PDF[BetaDistribution[alpha, beta], theta]*
     likelihood[theta, observations];), SaveDefinitions -> True]
 

